# Change button text in new MaterialDatePicker

Tags: android, android-datepicker, material-components, material-components-android

I am migrating the calendar components to the new Materials library, `MaterialDatePicker`, however I am having problems in doing something as simple as changing the name of the confirm button texts

Previously enough with this

```
datePickerDialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getString(R.string.save), datePickerDialog)
```

But now I can't find any public method

```
val picker = Builder.datePicker()
            picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener { selection: Long ->
                saveListPosition()
                accountDetailsPresenter.editDate(selection, transaction, product, "")
            }
picker.show(childFragmentManager, picker.toString())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently (`1.1.0-beta02` and `1.2.0-alpha02`) you can't do it programmatically.

However you can override the existing strings in your project, but this **workaround can stop to run** in the next releases.

For the confirm and the cancel buttons put in your projects these strings:

```
  <string name="mtrl_picker_confirm" description="Button text to indicate that the widget will save the user's selection [CHAR_LIMIT=16]">.....</string>
  <string name="mtrl_picker_cancel" description="Button text to indicate that the widget will ignore the user's selection [CHAR_LIMIT=16]" translatable="false">...</string>
```

[image]

Comment: Using this doesn't change the text on a samsung device :/ Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround to set button text programmatically and most important NOT for the entire project.

1. Create your date picker

   ```
        val picker : MaterialDatePicker<*> = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().build()
   ```
2. Find a positive or negative button by its id.

   ```
        picker?.view?.findViewById<Button>(com.google.android.material.R.id.confirm_button)?.text =
            "Your text here"

        picker?.view?.findViewById<Button>(com.google.android.material.R.id.cancel_button)?.text =
            "Your text here"
   ```

Comment: Try to check source code for com.google.android.material.datepicker.MaterialDatePicker, cuz my solution was made on material library 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE AS OF `1.4.0`**

There still isn't a public method for us to provide our custom texts for negative and positive buttons. For some reason, using `findViewById<Button>(com.google.android.material.R.id.confirm_button).text = "some text"` didn't work out for me. Instead add following lines to your string xmls to use your custom texts. (This will have app wide effects!) The difference between these and the ones [@Gabriele Mariotti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016562/gabriele-mariotti) provided are updated string resource ids.

```
<string description="Confirms the selection [CHAR_LIMIT=12]" name="mtrl_picker_save">Your positive button text</string>

<string name="cancel">Your negative button text</string>
```

Comment: Hi, I want to change Header *Selected date* text, and I am not able to do this using above solution. I am also using 1.4.0 version. Can you help?

Comment: Using this doesn't change the text on a samsung device :/ Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @UmairMustafa the solution I provided was not for Header

Comment: @tiagocarvalho92 are you using 1.4.0? Resource ids may have changed in newer versions (eg. 1.5.0)

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().apply {
    setTitleText("Start Date")
    setSelection(startDate.time)
}.build().apply {
    doOnStart {
        view?.findViewById<Button>(com.google.android.material.R.id.confirm_button)?.text = "Select"
        view?.findViewById<Button>(com.google.android.material.R.id.cancel_button)?.text = "Clear"
    }
    addOnPositiveButtonClickListener { date ->
        startDate = Date(date)
    }
    addOnNegativeButtonClickListener {
        setDate(null)
    }
}.show(childFragmentManager, "changeDate")
```

Comment: What is `doOnStart` and why is it needed in order to update the text? My project can't find a reference to `doOnStart`