# How to change Theme of "MaterialDatePicker" in Android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-datepicker, material-components-android, material-components

I've used **MaterialDatePicker** for the purpose of selecting a single date & also I had achieved that task but **I cannot change the theme** of the header & button.

```
        MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder;
        MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker;

        long today = MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds();
        CalendarConstraints.Builder con = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
        con.setValidator(DateValidatorPointForward.now());
        builder.setSelection(today);
        builder.setCalendarConstraints(con.build());

        materialDatePicker = builder.build();

        findViewById(R.id.startCalender).setOnClickListener(v ->
                materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), builder.toString())
        );

        materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(selection -> 
        Toast.makeText(this, materialDatePicker.getHeaderText(), 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
```

[image: Screenshot attached]

Comment: see their [samples](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) on github. that repo has examples on how to change themes and colors

Comment: @denvercoder9 Their samples are in Java, not Kotlin.  Also, they implement everything boilerplate from scratch.  Not a modularized solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have different options.
You can use:

```
builder.setTheme(R.style.MaterialCalendarTheme);
```

with:

```
  <style name="MaterialCalendarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <!-- just override the colors used in the default style -->
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryLightColor</item>
  </style>
```

or you can use something like:

```
  <style name="MaterialCalendarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">

    <!-- Header panel -->
    <item name="materialCalendarHeaderLayout">@style/MaterialCalendar.HeaderLayout1</item>
    <!-- Buttons -->
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/TextButton.Dialog1</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/TextButton.Dialog1</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MaterialCalendar.HeaderLayout1" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.HeaderLayout">
    <!--<item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>-->
    <item name="android:background">@color/primaryLightColor</item>
  </style>
  <style name="TextButton.Dialog1" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: This does not look like the real MaterialDatePicker from Google.  The positive/negative buttons don't end up being on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Hey, how I change the calendar background? Not header.

Comment: works perfectly for colors, but can't change positive and negative buttons texts, customizing this is such a pain 

Comment: @KostyanGorbach For the text check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287906/change-button-text-in-new-materialdatepicker/59288130#59288130