# How to change the color of the "MaterialDatePicker" in keyboard Mode & also it is possible to hide that mode in Android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-datepicker, material-components-android, material-components

I've changed the default theme of the **MaterialDatePicker** that link below, but I cannot change color in **keyboard mode** of the date selection & also it is possible to **hide** that mode?

[How to change Theme of "MaterialDatePicker" in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62086854/how-to-change-theme-of-materialdatepicker-in-android)[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the `TextInputLayout` in `MaterialDatePicker.INPUT_MODE_TEXT`.

It is a standard `TextInputLayout` which inherits from the `textInputStyle` attribute defined in your app theme.   In the default Material Components theme it is defined by `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox` and it is based on:

- background color(`boxBackgroundColor` attribute): `colorOnSurface`
- underline color (`boxStrokeColor` attribute) `colorPrimary`(focused) and `colorOnSurface` (other states)

Starting from **`1.3.0-alpha03`** you can use a theme:

```
   setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_App_MaterialCalendar)
```

with:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialCalendar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/Widget.App.TextInputLayout</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

Before the `1.3.0-alpha03` you can only change the default style of **all** `TextInputLayout`s in your app using the `textInputStyle` in your app theme.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   .... 
   <item name="textInputStyle">@style/My_FilledBox</item>
 </style>

 <style name="My_FilledBox" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
     ...
  </style>
```

[image]

---

There isn'a method to **hide the toggle** in the header, but there is a workaround (it can stop to work in the future releases):

```
builder.setTheme(R.style.MyMaterialCalendarTheme);
```

with:

```
 <style name="MyMaterialCalendarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <!-- HeaderToggleButton -->
    <item name="materialCalendarHeaderToggleButton">@style/HeaderToggleButton1</item>
 </style>

  <style name="HeaderToggleButton1" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.HeaderToggleButton">
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Nice clear answer! thanks